# What is the definition of multidimensional convex function?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let's say we have a function $f:\Bbb R^m\to\Bbb R^n$, what does it mean for $f$ to be convex?

I stumbled upon this term in article on high dimensional probability theory and I couldn't find a reference for it.

**PS.** I would really appreciate if you can also point me to a nice article or paper about basic theory about multidimensional convex functions.

Comment: Did the article not say what it meant? Perhaps there is some relevant order?

Comment: Sadly it didn't.

Comment: @copper.hat Actually it is more of a lecture note than an article. The topic is about Khintchine inequality and the contraction principle. (another term that I do not know what it means...)

Comment: Do you have a link for the lecture note?

Comment: @JohnDawkins http://www-personal.umich.edu/~romanv/teaching/2015-16/626/HDP-book-homework-3.pdf
It's the first sentence of page 134. (138 according to the pdf viewer)

Comment: The function $f$ has codomain $\mathbb{R}$, so it seems like a typo.

Comment: @LinAlg That's a very nice observation! I didn't notice that at all. I guess plowing through tons of material 3 hours straight can really damage one's reading comprehension... Thank you very much by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even in such a general setting as functional analysis (e.g., Brezis's book), the convexity of a function is defined as the convexity, as a set, of that function's *hypergraph*.  The definition of hypergraph, in turn, makes sense only when the function is scalar-valued.

Nevertheless, I found the following (see the very top of page 186): https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~dattorro/gcf.pdf

Comment: The hypergraph can be defined analogously for vector-valued functions, as long as you have a relevant order as @copper.hat noted.

Comment: There was a time when people were interested in this notion of convexity "with respect to a cone", which is what is being discussed in D'Attorro's book excerpt. But I recall going to a talk where it was basically shown that the notion just wasn't that useful. The few cases where such convexity resulted in tractable problems generally reduced or transformed to standard convex programs anyway.

Comment: +1, but do you by any chance understand the notation $\preceq_{\mathbb{R}_+^M}$ in that document? It defines convexity in terms of that, so without an explanation of the notation we're back to square 1.

Comment: Answering my own question, I found the whole book by searching on that domain - it's at https://convexoptimization.com/TOOLS/0976401304.pdf - this "generalised inequality" is defined toward the end of chapter 2.